# Asus Windows 7 laptop's external monitor has a yellow tint

Tags: windows-7, laptop, colors, external-display

I bought an Asus G73S laptop and plugged in my old monitor but noticed it had a yellow hue. At first I thought it was the cable but figured out that if I went to display settings and used the "Calibrate Color" wizard in Windows 7 it fixed the problem...at least until I logged off or the laptop went to sleep, which makes the problem come back (and I have to go back to Calibrate Color). What's strange is that even just clicking the first "Next" button in the Calibrate Color wizard will fix it and I just click next, next, next to use the defaults (or can even just cancel after the first next and the tint is gone).

I also thought it was the monitor I was using which was old and had no drivers available for Windows 7, but I recently replaced the monitor and the cable and the problem persists. This is VGA connection by the way. Don't know if using HDMI fixes it.

Edit: This question's old, I know, but I've never solved the problem. However, I have noticed new insights into what the issue might be. It turns out not to be the fact that I'm connecting to an external monitor, I noticed a change in the color even when using the laptop's screen (albeit it's harder to notice). And if I correct the problem on the laptop's screen and then connect to an external monitor, the issue remains corrected. Not sure if I should edit the title of this question or not.

I'm thinking it might be some software doing it, maybe one of Asus's programs that came preinstalled. I could try uninstalling things, but I'm hesitant to do so. Does anyone think some software might be fiddling with color settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.systemshock.org/index.php?topic=4075.0

I recently started having the same problem on my new Asus notebook. The culprit is a bloatware called Asus splendid utility. Either uninstalling or selecting normal in the option of app will fix this issue for sure.

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm hopeful that might've done the trick, though on mine it was called "ASUS Splendid Video Enhancement Technology". I didn't see a "Splendid Utility". I'm going to give it a few days to see if the problem creeps up again and then come back and mark yours as the answer if I don't see the yellow tint again :)

Comment: @Bob that program you have is the sure culprit. Kill me if not :) just get rid of bloatware and get peace of mind.

Comment: I haven't seen any yellow tint, I think getting rid of that solved the problem. Thanks again

Comment: I had the same problem using Windows 8, and uninstalling Splendid Utility appears to have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

There a few possibilities - one is that the monitor has a lower colour temperature set - this seems like the more likely option and should be easy to fix - mess around with the monitor's onboard controls

From the fact that its always the same colour rules out the other possibility, that its a bad backlight.

Comment: It's definitely not the monitor or the cable. I've purchased a new monitor with a new cable and the problem exists. I also just checked and the color is set to Standard rather than Warm

Comment: there's no cool setting?

Comment: There is, but how would that fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So a friend fixed it for me, though I still don't really know what the problem was. I set the NVidia driver, through the NVidia control panel, to use NVidia settings for my external monitor. That seemed to fix it. Like I said, I don't know aspect of Win 7 or whatever software was running that was causing the issue in the first place.

ETA: Spoke too soon. It didn't fix it. I tried putting the computer to sleep then logged back in and it went back to a yellowish tint.